# Predicate should concatenate and reverse, but always returns false

Tags: prolog

I am new at Prolog and just started practising the built-in list predicates. So I was trying to write a code that concatenates two lists and order them descending(reverse them). The problem is that the code always returns false, and I have no idea why it doesn't return what I am expecting.

`reverse(append([6,5,4],[3,2,1]),Y).`
Also tried:
`reverse(append([6,5,4],[3,2,1],X),Y).` & `reverse(append([6,5,4],[3,2,1],X),X).`
But none of them actually worked. I would be thankful if someone can tell me the solution.

Comment: prolog is not a functional programming language. You should for example `append([6,5,4],[3,2,1], X), reverse(X, Y).`

Comment: Do not post pictures of ocde. Also, appned?

Comment: I guess failure in Prolog means error and failure, even more so in the future.

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse I sure hope not. Errors (more correctly, anomalies or faults as people who revel in distilling vocabulary usage would like to tell us) and "proof failures" are two completely different things and I hope this stays this way. I am about ti channel my inner Niklaus Wirth here.

Comment: @David Tonhofer reverse/2 is non-trivial, check out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66251859/502187

Comment: @gusbro Thank you so much. This worked as expected. I just figured out that I was so close to the solution. I tried  ```append([1,2,3],[4,5,6],X).
reverse(X,Y).``` but instead putting a '.' I should've put a ','

Comment: @TA_intern Bad position I guess. The code had no syntax errors, I just had a typo in the question, just like your comment. Also, would like to know why I should not post pictures of the code.

Comment: @Sam: Your edit is wrong. In this question, reverse/2 is not a built-in.

Comment: @DuDa: see above comment

Comment: @OmarOshiba I don't have tpyos, what are you talking about? But see [this Q/A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) on the topic of images in questions.