# Can single sided unification improve error handling?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, unification

Inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66248785/502187), I am trying to harden error
handling of reverse/2. So I tried this implementation:

```
reverse(X, Y) :- reverse(X, [], Y).

reverse(X, _, _) :- var(X), throw(error(instantiation_error,_)).
reverse([], X, R) :- !, R = X.
reverse([X|Y], Z, R) :- !, reverse(Y, [X|Z], R).
reverse(X, _, _) :- throw(error(type_error(list,X),_)).
```

Everything works fine, until I try reverse/2 as a generator:

```
?- reverse([1,2,3],X).
X = [3, 2, 1].

?- reverse(2,X).
ERROR: Type error: `list' expected, found `2' (an integer)

?- reverse(X,Y).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Can single sided unification change the situation, some typical solution based on single sided unification so that the generator `reverse(X,Y)` would still work? Single sided unification is available in SWI-Prolog 8.3.19.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid I cannot present a single sided unification solution. Its rather that normal unification in the form of `(\=)/2` could be useful. I hardly use `(\=)/2` ever. The solution is inspired by Dijkstra guards if-fi, link to paper at end of this post:

```
if
Cond1 -> ActionList1
..
Condn -> ActionList2
fi
```

The if-fi aborts if none of the conditions Cond1,..,Condn is satisfied. So we
simply use a conjunction of the negation of the conditions:

```
reverse(X, Y) :- reverse(X, [], Y).

reverse(X, _, _) :- X \= [], X \= [_|_], throw(error(type_error(list,X),_)).
reverse([], X, R) :- R = X.
reverse([X|Y], Z, R) :- reverse(Y, [X|Z], R).
```

Seems to work:

```
?- reverse([1,2,3],X).
X = [3, 2, 1].

?- reverse(2,X).
ERROR: Type error: `list' expected, found `2' (an integer)

?- reverse(X,Y).
X = Y, Y = [] ;
X = Y, Y = [_1778] ;
X = [_1778, _2648],
Y = [_2648, _1778] ;
Etc..
```

So single sided unification might be the wrong approach? I dont know. The above solution incures an overhead, unless some indexing might optimize away `(\=)/2`. Could even work in connection with attributed variables.

**Nondeterminacy and Formal Derivation of Programs**
Edsger W. Dijkstra - Burroughs Corporation
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.90.97&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (a straightforward translation to use `=>` of reverse/2 in library(lists)):

```
reverse(List, Reversed) =>
    reverse(List, [], Reversed, Reversed).

reverse([], Ys, Reversed, Tail) =>
    Reversed = Ys,
    Tail = [].
reverse([X|Xs], Rs, Reversed, Tail) =>
    Tail = [_|Bound],
    reverse(Xs, [X|Rs], Reversed, Bound).
```

Comment: See my questions, it says "generator reverse(X,Y) would still work? " Doesn't work on my side. Still gives ?- reverse(X,Y). ERROR: No rule matches reverse(_2624,[],_2628,_2628) .